# Sending action to parent component Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 components one is a `Topbar` and the second is a `Display` here they are:

Display:

```
import {Component, View, NgIf} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {Topbar} from '../topbar/topbar';

@Component({
  selector: 'display'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/display/display.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/display/display.css'],
  directives: [Topbar, NgIf]
})

export class Display {
    showGrid: boolean;

    constructor(){
        this.showGrid = true;
    }
}
```

Display HTML(important for my issue):

```
<topbar></topbar>
<div *ng-if="showGrid" class="display-list">
    <h1>true</h1>
</div>
<div *ng-if="showGrid == false" class="display-list">
    <h1>false</h1>
</div>
```

As you can see I have an if statement depending on the `showGrid` property. Now here is my Topbar component:

Topbar:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'topbar'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/topbar/topbar.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/topbar/topbar.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class Topbar {
  toggleGrid(){
    // update Display showGrid property
  }
}
```

Topbar HTML:

```
<div (click)="toggleGrid()" class="col-md-1 no-padding grid-toggle">
  <img src="assets/imgs/icons/icon-list.svg">
</div>
```

As you can see I have a function `toggleGrid` this function is to toggle the `Display` property `showGrid`; however, I can't seem to find a way to get this done. Since `Topbar` is a directive of `Display` I can't inject `Display` into `Topbar`. I've tried creating a service but the issue with this is that it doesn't update the `Display` `showGrid` property

Comment: Don't you have a design issue? I would treat topbar and display as siblings and use them in a parent component.

Comment: `Display` is `Topbar`'s parent, so yes, you can inject it using `@Host()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is two approaches:

**1.**

You just need to define some `toggle-grid` event (output property) for your `<toolbar>` component and then listen to it in your `Display` component. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfPBi2vRThmFN0jCrObb?p=preview).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'topbar'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div (click)="onButtonClick()">
      Button
    </div>
  `
})
export class Topbar {
  @Output() toggleGrid = new EventEmitter();

  onButtonClick() {
    this.toggleGrid.next();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'display'
})
@View({
  directives: [Topbar, NgIf],
  template: `
    <topbar (toggle-grid)="toggleGrid()"></topbar>
    <div *ng-if="showGrid" class="display-list">
        <h1>true</h1>
    </div>
    <div *ng-if="showGrid == false" class="display-list">
        <h1>false</h1>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Display {
    showGrid: boolean = true;

    toggleGrid() {
      this.showGrid = !this.showGrid;
    }
}
```

**2.**

Use [`@Host`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.42/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L239) and maybe [`forwardRef`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.42/modules/angular2/src/core/di/forward_ref.ts#L42) to inject parent component into child. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uVGuQo8Fl7uPisekZtc5?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'topbar'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div (click)="onButtonClick()">
      Button
    </div>
  `
})
export class Topbar {
  display: Display;

  constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => Display)) display: Display) {
    this.display = display;
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.display.toggleGrid()
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'display'
})
@View({
  directives: [Topbar, NgIf],
  template: `
    <topbar></topbar>
    <div *ng-if="showGrid" class="display-list">
        <h1>true</h1>
    </div>
    <div *ng-if="showGrid == false" class="display-list">
        <h1>false</h1>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Display {
    showGrid: boolean = true;

    toggleGrid() {
      this.showGrid = !this.showGrid;
    }
}
```

Personally, I much prefer the first approach as it makes data flow of your application to be more explicit.

Comment: This works for me. But could you please explain how to pass some data in this event?

Comment: UPD. Find answer:(toggle-grid)="toggleGrid( $event)"